# Why do I still see a useraccount in the people picker, but this user account is deleted in AD?

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-server, people-picker

I am using sp 2010. I see for one employee 2 user accounts in the people picker. Only the domain name is difference between these 2 user accounts. We have removed all the users from domainA. All the users from domainB are still available. We did a full AD Sync. You still see 2 user accounts in the people picker. When I go to the userprofile service application and search to the username I see only 1 results. It is the useraccount of domainB.

How can I remove these users from domainA from the people picker?

**UPDATE**

When I go to this url inside some website "http://myCompany.com/_catalogs/users/simple.aspx" I see a hidden list with useraccounts. When I remove here users, they are not visible in the people picker from this website. But how to remove users from this hidden list from the whole web application?

Answer (score 3):

People Picker checks both the User Information List of the given Site Collection and Active Directory for the users.

Looks Like the entries are in the User Information list. You can manually delete it from UIL(/_catalogs/users/simple.aspx).

Also check this blog, very informative.

http://blog.octavie.nl/index.php/2010/10/12/my-challenge-with-the-people-picker

Answer (score 0):

I think You have a entry in the user information list.

Look here 
http://zimmergren.net/technical/sharepoints-hidden-user-list-user-information-list

It is a normal list that holds the assigned Users.

Maybe that solle your Problem.

Otherwise you can resstrict the peoplepicker scope